# how to calculate the difference between rows and number of levels based on group in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a big data frame. I would like to calculate the difference between the row with the above row in `"pos"` column, only working on the rows when the columns equal to 1 (such as `df$X1x8 == 1`), then find out the maximum of the differences for each level of `"chr"` column, and `nlevels(df$bin)`. I need R experts to solve my problem. appreciate it.
EXAMPLE: if working on colum `X1x8` (column 4 to 8 comtain only 0 or 1)

```
df = read.table(text=" mi   chr pos X1x3    X1x4    X1x8    X2x3    X2x4    sum bin
S000001 1   12578   0   1   1   0   1   3   1
S000003 1   96483   0   0   1   0   0   1   2
S000007 1   238450  1   0   1   1   0   3   3
S000010 1   298018  0   0   1   0   0   1   3
S000015 1   471895  0   1   0   1   1   3   4
S000022 1   704591  0   0   1   0   0   1   5
S000023 1   757938  1   0   1   1   1   4   5
S000002 2   47285   0   0   1   0   1   2   6
S000005 2   145243  0   1   1   0   0   2   6
S000009 2   246104  1   0   1   1   0   3   7
S000011 2   319046  0   1   1   0   0   2   7
S000018 2   566163  1   0   0   1   1   3   9", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df <- df[order(df$chr,df$pos),] # to make sure entries are in right order
dat <- df[!(df$X1x8==0),] # only calculate df$column == 1 rows
dat = dat[,c(1:3,6,10)] # is just example for working column 6
bin <- nlevels(as.factor(dat$bin))
# the first dat$pos of each level of "chr" should give to the first dat$diff, then the rest of values are filled with the following code. 
data.frame(diff(as.matrix(dat$pos))) 
max(dat$diff)

 my expect the result looks like:
#chr  1x3   1x4 1x8 2x3 2x4 
#gab    1   519488  459317  406573  286043  459317 
#bin    1   2   2   4   3   3 
#gab    2   320059  173803  100861  320059 518878 
#bin    2   2   2   2   2   2
```

Comment: Not gonna lie... I tried following the logic here and I'm confused.  Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit:

So you've provided the actual expected output (I've updated your question), so here is the updated code

```
dat <- split(df, df$chr)
vars <- grep("X", names(df), value = T)
dat2 <- data.frame(gap = numeric(length(unique(df$chr))*length(vars)) , bin = numeric(length(unique(df$chr))*length(vars)))
k <- 0
for (i in 1:length(dat)){
  for(j in vars){
    k <- k + 1
    dat2$gap[k] <- max(diff(dat[[as.character(i)]][dat[[as.character(i)]][j] == 1, "pos"]))
    dat2$bin[k] <- nlevels(as.factor(dat[[as.character(i)]][dat[[as.character(i)]][j] == 1, "bin"]))
  }
}
dat3 <- data.frame(chr = paste(c("gab", "bin"), rep(unique(df$chr), each = 2)))
dat3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(dat3, t(do.call(cbind, split(dat2, gl(length(unique(df$chr)), length(vars)))))))
names(dat3) <- c("chr", gsub("^X", "", vars))
row.names(dat3) <- NULL
dat3
##    chr    1x3    1x4    1x8    2x3    2x4
##1 gab 1 519488 459317 406573 286043 459317
##2 bin 1      2      2      4      3      3
##3 gab 2 320059 173803 100861 320059 518878
##4 bin 2      2      2      2      2      2
```

Comment: My result I posted was fake not real one. this was just to show the format. Your code is almost there. So you need to make some modifications Thanks.The real result for the example df is:   chr 1x3 1x4 1x8 2x3 2x4
gab 1 519488 459317 406573 286043 459317
bin 1 2 2 4 3 3
gab 2 320059 173803 100861 320059 518878
bin 2 2 2 2 2 2